# How can QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene support synchronous zooming and panning on multiple QGraphicsPixmapItems?

Tags: python, pyqt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have a viewing model that is based on PyQt `QGraphicsView` and `QGraphicsScene`.
I add two items to the scene. 
That part is working well.

However, when I choose to scale the view, using the `scale(factor,factor)` api, the left item takes much more area than the right one.
I would like to have a possibility to symmetrically display the scale effect on both items.

Alternatively, I would like to have two instances of `QGraphicsView` that listen simultaneously to the events of `wheelEvent` (in order to focus) and to the `RubberBandDrag` function in order to have the panning at the same time on all `QGraphicsView` instances.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
class PhotoViewer(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    photoClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QPoint)

    def __init__(self, parent,theLayout):
        super(PhotoViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self._zoom = 0
        self.layout = theLayout
        self._empty = True
        self.parent = parent
        self._scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self._photo = QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self._photo1 = QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self._scene.addItem(self._photo)
        self._scene.addItem(self._photo1)
        self.setScene(self._scene)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtGui.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtGui.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(30, 30, 30)))
        self.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.NoFrame)

    def hasPhoto(self):
        return not self._empty


    def setPhoto(self, pixmap=None):
        self._zoom = 0
        width = self.parent.width()
        height= self.height()
        self._scene.setSceneRect(QRectF(0.0, 0.0, width + 20.0, height))
        if pixmap and not pixmap.isNull():
            self._empty = False
            self.setDragMode(QtGui.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
            pixmap =pixmap.scaled(width/2,height)
            self._photo.setPixmap(pixmap)
            image = QPixmap("IMG_1612_02_1120_1542_bp.bmp")
            image = image.scaled(width/2, height)
            self._photo1.setPixmap(image)
            self._photo.setOffset(0,0.0)
            self._photo1.setOffset(width / 2 + 20, 0.0)
            self.scale(1.5, 1.5)
```

Comment: Can you please show some code that you've tried?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Hi, I shared my code above.